# PHP: Interpolating a PHP variable in a string block

Tags: php, string-interpolation

So, in Perl and PHP, you can produce a block of text using a number of the "<" symbols:
Perl:

```
return <<TEXT;
    <a href=$foo>Perl interpolates this properly</a>
TEXT
```

PHP:

```
return <<<TEXT
    <a href=$bar>PHP does not interpolate this...</a>
TEXT;
```

So, my question is, is there a way to (cleanly) do this in PHP like in Perl?
I have tried `<?...?>` and `<?php...?>`, but they do the same thing...
Also, this is really a subset of the entire block of text... otherwise I would just build the string.

Comment: So, what about it isn't working? What do you mean by "(cleanly)" ? Expected and actual outcome?

Comment: I should have specified, it isn't interpolating "$foo" like it should be. I believe I should put my foot in mouth, though. I believe Frits answered it, and showed me what I was doing incorrectly... I never tried it without the php tags...

Comment: PHP heredocs interpolate variables in the doc by default, as if it were a double quoted string. Your posted code should work just fine.

Comment: Enable `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. If `$foo` isn't defined, there is no interpolation to be expected.

Comment: Maybe it's not interpolating $foo because your PHP example uses $bar... :)

Comment: My second reply said I should put my foot in mouth... I have the correct syntax here, but did not in my code... I didn't even notice it until I saw Frits' answer...

Comment: Your Perl HERE doc syntax is WRONG.  (I can't speak for the PHP syntax).  The semicolon is mis-placed.  It doesn't belong at the terminating "`TEXT`", it belongs after the opening `TEXT`, as in "`return <<TEXT;`".  As you have it written, the terminator will never be found.  You mention the semicolon isn't needed for Perl.  But even placing it on the same line as the here-doc terminator is not going to work.  Elevate "unnecessary" to "incorrect."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's called heredoc syntax:

```
$str = <<<EOD
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using heredoc syntax.
EOD;
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Obviously he already knew that syntax, as shown by OPs second example. His inquiry was about variables within there. Did you get what specifically his inquiry was about?

Comment: I have no clue what OP means. Maybe he wrote it as bare text file (no enclosing <?php markers), or did not start the HEREDOC marker at the line beginning, or whatever .. ?

Comment: Frits, even though you didn't answer my question directly (I had the string block syntax down), looking at the link, I saw that I had not tried just using the variable without any php blocks (without noticing, as my syntax here is correct). I still need to verify it works, and I'll get back to you guys!

Answer (score 2):

PHP Heredocs are treated just like double-quoted strings, so if you intent is the have the value of $bar shown in the final string, this should work.